# What was the official purpose of the fuel pod hauled by Furiosa in Mad Max: Fury Road?

Tags: plot-explanation, mad-max-fury-road, mad-max

We learn that it would be the price for the War Rig's safe passage through the biker territory, as negotiated previously by Furiosa. However, the deal couldn't obviously be a part of Immortan Joe's original plan.

When Furiosa and the Rig are introduced, we learn that the original mission was to take water (aqua cola) and mothers' milk to Gas Town and Bullet Farm. Nothing is said about the fuel pod however. Its being full seems out of place because why would anyone bring fuel to Gas Town? They have plenty of it!

The deal was most likely to bring the fuel *back* from Gas Town in exchange for the food products, so in that case the fuel pod should be empty. I doubt that the same tanker would be used to haul water and fuel, so the pod being empty to bring home guzzoline would be logical.

I also doubt that it would be used for refueling since all the settlements are relatively close to each other. The Gas Town is clearly visible from the Citadel and the Bullet Farm cannot be much further, since both settlements' war parties arrive roughly at the same time.

Is it possible that Furiosa somehow managed to sneak 3000 gallons of precious guzzoline into the pod under Immortan Joe's watchful eye? It seems unlikely since it must have required some cooperation of a couple of Immortan's subjects and the movie does not hint at any conspiracy. It would also be fairly easy to notice the difference between a full and an empty pod (weight difference could be noticed by the lift operators, it would also influence the shape of the tires).

Or did the pod serve some other purpose, which I fail to recognize at the moment? Or is it just a <s>gaping</s> plot hole?

Comment: It's maybe a tiny plot hole. I wouldn't call it gaping. Note that the crew that goes with Furiosa is fairly loyal and works under her command for quite a while before realizing something was up. War Boys didn't seem especially sharp and were all eager to please so it's quite plausible that Furiosa simply managed to convince enough of them that it made sense to pull a full fuel pod.

Answer (score 4):

The *"movie does not hint at any conspiracy"*, nor should it, as it's heralded* for not having used *'backstory'* or *'explanations'* for anything:

> *A stand-alone piece, Fury Road is unapologetic in its refusal to explain the previous three films of the franchise - and their Australian settings - nor even much about its titular hero. –[nzherald.co.nz](http://www.nzherald.co.nz/entertainment/news/article.cfm?c_id=1501119&objectid=11444771)

The fuel pod was 'officially' supposed to be empty:

> "Once again, we send off my war rig to **bring back guzzoline from gas town** and bullets from the bullet farm." –Joe

It's not a plot hole, it's intentionally left out to develop a **plot twist**.

Comment: Why should a potential subplot about an internal conspiracy against Immortan Joe be considered backstory or a throwback to the original films?

Comment: @Przemek That information is integral only to Fury Road's [plot twist](https://www.google.com/search?q=plot+twist&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). Remember though, *'conspiracy against the head bad guy'* is a persistent theme in #2 and 3, which easily carries over into 4, needing no explanation. Had it been explained, it *would* have been a throwback; Part Duex. Instead only are *we* given the information that Joe is crazy and a control freak. No dissension is presented to us until Furiousa's.